# Error when duplicating rows and changing a value in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I know there are similar questions on SO but I wasn't able to find my exact use case. I am trying to duplicate some rows in a PostgreSQL table and change one value in them. For example, I have a table with three values and I want to grab a selection of rows based on the third value and copy them, then change the third value. Here's what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO my_table ( val1, val2, val3 )
VALUES
    (
        ( SELECT val1 FROM my_table WHERE val3 = '1' LIMIT 2, ( SELECT val2 FROM my_table WHERE val3 = '1' LIMIT 2), '2' )
```

I am getting an error that says "`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`". Also, I would like to be able to test the solution with just a couple rows, so ideally I would be able to limit the `SELECT` statements to just a couple. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VALUES` keyword is used when you're inserting manual values into the table. If you want to insert based on a query, you skip that.

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (val1, val2, val3)
SELECT val1, val2, '2'
FROM my_table 
WHERE val3 = '1'
LIMIT 2;
```